# Has Syncfusion.EJ2.HtmlMVCExtension been removed from Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, syncfusion, asp-net-mvc-1

Without this extension, fluent syntax does not work.
I cannot get this to work in Syncfusion Asp.Net Core.
In AspNet MVC this ran because of a class:  Syncfusion.EJ2.HtmlMVCExtension

I get this error:
*The type or namespace name 'HtmlMVCExtension' does not exist in the namespace 'Syncfusion.EJ2' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*

```
@using Syncfusion.EJ2.HtmlMVCExtension
@(Html.EJS().Grid<Object>("FlatGrid")
            .Datasource((IEnumerable<object>)ViewBag.DataSource)
            .AllowPaging()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided information, we suspect that you want to render our components using HtmlHelper in Asp.Net Core application. We have prepared sample for your reference.

Sample link:
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/CoreMvcApp-60909786
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/CoreRazorPages-313511621

Could you please check the above sample and revert us with the below information if still issue persist?

1. Your project details such as .Net Core or .Net Framework, Core with MVC application or razor pages, etc.
2. Please share your code snippet. If possible, please share issue reproducible sample.

Doc - Core Getting started link:
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/getting-started/visual-studio-2017/